# Inserting Hidden Form Values To Database With AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

After my user drops photos to a drop zone thumbnails appear of the images and an input field appears allows the user to add comma delimited tags to the images.

There are three tables in the database,
Table 1. stores the id type of the the tag which is always 11 for images,
Table 2.  Name of the tags and the id given to each tag. 
Table 3. The Target URL Path to an image, the tag id, the tag name, the file name.

Table 3 never populates anything but the other two tables populate fine.

I can console.log out the values till I get to this ajax call where in the console i'm showing a bunch of data that is a bit confusing to me. I am assuming I am grabbing the data wrong from the form and my values are not holding what I think they are holding which is why Table three wont populate.

This is how I am creating the hidden form fields as well as the input text field,

```
 //Create an empty container
    var path = "users/" + $("#username").val() + "/";
    var $elems = $();
    //Cycle thru the files
    $.each(data.files, function(idx, file) {
        //Create an input with attrs
        var $inputType = $("<input/>", {
            'type': 'hidden',
            'value': '11',
            'id': 'tag_type_id', 
            'name': 'tag_type_id'
        });

        var $inputName = $("<input/>", {
            'type': 'hidden',
            'value': file["name"],
            'id': 'tag_target_name', 
            'name': 'tag_target_name'
        });

        var $inputURL = $("<input/>", {
            'type': 'hidden',
            'value': path + file["name"],         
            'id': 'tag_target_url', 
            'name': 'tag_target_url'
        });    

        var $inputTags = $("<input/>", {
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Seperate tags with commas',
            'id': 'tags', 
            'name': 'tags' 
        });
```

This is my ajax function which i am using console.log to show the data I have at this point before I send it all over to my php script,

```
function addTags(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'data/add_tags.php',
        data: "&tag_type_id=" + $('#tag_type_id').val() + "&tag_target_name=" + $('#tag_target_name').val() +
            "&tag_target_url=" + $('#tag_target_url').val() + "&tags=" + $('#tags').val(),    
                success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response === 'error'){
                        $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('Please add tags seperated by commas');
                $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/error.png" height="50" width="50">');
                $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)   
            }
            else {
                    $('.messageText').empty()
                    $('.messageImage').empty()
                    $('.messageText').append('Your tags have been added.');
                    $(".messageImage").append('<img src="images/success.png" height="50" width="50">');
                    $('.message').slideDown(400).delay(10000).fadeOut(400)  
                    console.log(tag_type_id);
                    console.log(tag_target_name);
                    console.log(tag_target_url);
                    console.log(tags);

            }   
       }
    });
 };
```

add_tags.php

```
<?php
//Include files                 
require_once('../classes/class_login.php');

$tag_type_id = $_POST['tag_type_id'];
$tag_target_name = $_POST['tag_target_name'];
$tag_target_url = $_POST['tag_target_url'];
$tags = $_POST['tags'];

    /*** begin with some validation ***/
    if(!isset($_POST['tag_type_id'], $_POST['tag_target_name'], $_POST['tag_target_url'], $_POST['tags']))
    {
        /*** if no POST is submited ***/
        $msg = 'Please Submit a tag';
        print('error');
    }
    elseif(filter_var($_POST['tag_type_id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("min_range"=>1, "max_range"=>100)) == false)
    {
        /*** if tag is too short ***/
        $msg = 'Invalid Tag Type';
                print('error');
    }
    elseif( strlen($_POST['tag_target_url']) == 0 )
    {
        /*** if tag is too long ***/
        $msg = 'Tag target is required';
                print('error');
    }
    elseif( strlen($_POST['tags']) == 0 )
    {
        $msg = 'Tag Required';
                print('error');
    }
    elseif(  strlen($_POST['tag_target_name']) == 0 )
    {
        $msg = 'Tag Name is too short';
                print('error');
    }
    elseif( strlen($_POST['tag_target_name']) > 30 )
    {
        $msg = 'Tag Name is too long!';
                print('error');
    }
    else
    {
        /*** if we are here, all is well ***/

        $tag_type_id = filter_var($_POST['tag_type_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $tag_target_url = filter_var($_POST['tag_target_url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $tag_target_name = filter_var($_POST['tag_target_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $tags = filter_var($_POST['tags'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            addTags($tag_type_id, $tag_target_name, $tag_target_url, $tags);

            $msg = 'Tag Type Added!';
                    print('success');
        }

?>
```

I am thinking maybe I am actually holding some type of object instead of the default values I think I am adding to the hidden form fields and that is causing the problem at this point.

If someone with more ajax or JS experience would mind looking at this and tell me if this look typical or where I might be going wrong I would appreciate it.

This is some of the data in the console when i submit a new tag to an image, These drop down with all kinds of info in them. but as you can see the ids are all correct for the input fields. And when I console.log out at the form stage the correct values show in the console... but when I get to the ajax call its like a bunch more data shows up...

```
  [input#tag_type_id, select#tag_type_id, tag_type_id: input#tag_type_id]
data_handling.js:353 [input#tag_target_name, input#tag_target_name, tag_target_name: input#tag_target_name]
data_handling.js:354 <input type=​"hidden" value=​"users/​nichodiaz/​o-red.png" id=​"tag_target_url" name=​"tag_target_url">​
data_handling.js:355 [input#tags, input#tags, tags: input#tags]
```